# Android RelativeLayout: layout_above appears to behave incorrectly with layout_alignBaseline

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

In Android I am trying to do a RelativeLayout in which I want to use layout_above on something that is aligned with layout_alignBaseline, but find that this is not working correctly.

Note: I tested with API levels 14, 15, and am going to check in 19 (latest) as soon as I get that installed, with the same result. By the way, I'm referring to appearance in Eclipse layout editing GUI - I haven't tested on a real device, but I assume it's supposed to be consistent...

My real layout is complicated but I have reduced it to this simple example:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/a"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="A"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/b"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/a"
        android:text="B"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/c"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_above="@id/b"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="C"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

With this layout, I would expect to see the letter A at bottom right (yes), the letter B at bottom left (yes), and the letter C immediately above the letter B. In fact, the letter C does not appear - it seems to have been positioned off the top of the view.

If you replace the layout_alignBaseline on B with layout_alignTop or alignBottom, because in this example A has the same font size, this does not change the appearance of A and B at all - but now C appears in the correct place.

My basic question is, why does this not work when using the baseline alignment? Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Notes:

1. Obviously in this simplified example there is no reason to use layout_alignBaseline, but it is necessary in cases where the font sizes are not the same.
2. This is not an urgent problem because I have come up with a less neat way to achieve a similar layout. But I'd like to know for future reference why it doesn't work.
3. I did look at the related questions but didn't spot the answer.

Comment: It might be a bug. There is a known bug with layout_alignParentBottom which makes the parent be maximum height. That has never been fixed.

Comment: Bug AFAICT https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/M9THu9V08vo